# Gson and Jackson incompatibility

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, jackson, gson

Currently I'm working on two projects: one is using Java 1.5 and Spring 3.2.3, and the other is using Java 1.8 and Spring 4.1.5. As you may know, since Spring 4.x.x default `HttpMessageConverter` is Gson. Prior to version 4.x.x default was Jackson. I thought this will not influence compatibility, but lo and behold: it does... Specifically I'm talking about `java.util.Date` parsing/mapping.

Assume that I have a class as below (`equals()` and `hashCode()` methods are ommited):

```
public class FooBar {
    public String str = getRandomStringEncodedInUTF8();
    public Date date = new Date(0); //1970-01-01 00:00:00
}

public void retrieveFooBars() {
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<HashSet<FooBar>>(){}.getType();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().
        registerTypeAdapter(FooBar.class, new FooBarDeserializer()).create();

    String ipAddress = getIpAddress();
    RestTemplate request = new RestTemplate();

    String gsonString;
    try {
        gsonString = request.getForObject("http://"
            + ipAddress+ ":8080/foobars/get", String.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }

    Set<FooBar> fooBars = gson.fromJson(gsonString, collectionType);
}
```

`FooBarDeserializer` is as follows:

```
public class FooBarDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<FooBar> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat
        .forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public FooBar deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
        JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();

        JsonElement str = obj.get("str");
        if (str != null)
        if (!str.isJsonNull()) {
            fooBar.str = originalId.getAsString();
        }

        JsonElement date = obj.get("date");
        if (date != null)
        if (!date.isJsonNull()) {
            String temp = date.getAsString();

            if (temp != null) {
                fooBar.date = dateFormatter.parseDateTime(temp).toDate();
            }
        }
        return FooBar;
    }
}
```

If I don't use `FooBarDeserializer` I get `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1970-01-01` caused by: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1970-01-01"` So far so good. I can receive data, plus keep my UTF-8 encoding.

Problem is when sending data to server with older version of Spring:

```
public void distributeFooBars() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(FooBar.class, new FooBarSerializer()).create();

    String ipAddress = getIpAddress();
    Set<FooBar> newFooBars = getNewFooBars();

    RestTemplate request = new RestTemplate();
    String gsonString = gson.toJson(newFooBars);
    try {
        request.postForObject("http://" + ipAddress + ":8080/foobars/set",
            gsonString, Boolean.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

If I don't use explicitly Gson prior to sending newFooBars to "older" server, and let `GsonHttpMessageConverter` to do it's job, I preserve my UTF-8 string, but parsing the Date fails since it's written as "jan 1, 1970". If I do explicitly use Gson and converting newFooBars to String prior to sending them, I lose UTF-8 characters (i.e. instead of ČĆĐŠŽ_čćđšž i would receive ?????_?????) but parsing the date doesn't throw an Exception. Customer serializer is:

```
public class FooBarSerializer implements JsonSerializer<FooBar> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(FooBar fooBar, Type type,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {

        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.addProperty("str", fooBar.str);

        String date = null;
        if (fooBar.date != null) {
            date = formatter.print(fooBar.date.getTime());
        }
        obj.addProperty("date", date);

        return obj;
    }
}
```

SIDE NOTE: if using Gson explicitly, on older server controller has the following mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/set", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
```

else it's:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/set", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

Otherwise I get 415 Unsupported media type.

I know it has been a long post, but I would be grateful to anyone that can help me. So my **QUESTION** is:

**Is there a way to solve this problem? Like having a system wide Gson serializer but just for `java.util.Date`. Or setting that forces UTF-8 encoding for plain/text?**

Comment: Jackson is still chosen first in Spring 4. At least it is if you use the default `@EnableWebMvc` config.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis could you elaborate? I have spring-webmvc as maven dependency in my project. Plus I have <mvc:annotation-driven /> tag in my servlet.xml file. But still, I get `RestTemplate:770 - Writing [[FooBar [str=ČĆĐŠŽ_čćđšž, date=... using ... GsonHttpMessageConverter`

Comment: Might not be relevant to your question, but if Jackson is on your classpath, the Jackson `HttpMessageConverter` will be registered, regardless of if Gson is on your classpath. If Jackson isn't and Gson is, the Gson `HttpMessageConverter` will be registered.

Comment: I have them both: `jackson-core-2.5.1` and `gson-2.3.1`. Is there a way to force `JacksonHttpMessageConverter` over Gson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After excluding `gson-2.3.1.jar` from my build path, `Jackson2HttpMessageConverter` became default. Gson was a dependency in common piece of code so in pom.xml I added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>common_code</artifactId>
    <version>6.9</version>

    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

After that, the problem weren't `Date` objects but joda `DateTime` objects. Adding `jackson-datatype-joda` as maven dependency resolved that issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything works as expected now...
Sotirios Delimanolis thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I know of to handle this (as of GSON 2.8.2):

**1 Tell GSON which pattern to use:**

https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setDateFormat-java.lang.String-

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
```

**2 Create a new DateSerializer just for the type `Date`:**

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

@Override
public Date deserialize(JsonElement element, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2) {

    // Do your stuff here...

    String dateString = element.getAsString();
    Long val = Long.valueOf(dateString);
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(val);       
    Date date = new Date(timestamp.getTime());
    return date;
  }

}
```

And use it:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
```

This solved my problem without excluding anything.